# Use code analysis with Visual Studio DNX project (.xproj)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, code-analysis, .net-core

Within the properties of an "ordinary" Visual Studio project (.csproj) it's possible to say *Enable Code Analysis on Build* (formerly known as FxCop).

Since I've started playing around with new DNX projects (.xproj) I'm searching for something similar. I know there may be no build output, so the old approach may not really fit into this, but I'm quite sure the Code Analysis / FxCop rules still apply. Furthermore there should be some way to register a custom rule set (.ruleset) file within the new "actual" project file (project.json).

Maybe I'm overlooking something more modern based on Roslyn or the like?

Comment: I think this https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2311 is required for this.

Comment: Ah, seems this question can get an answer with beta7 (at the earliest).

Comment: It is not in beta7 and currently is not assigned to a milestone...

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I still can't run it in `xproj` projects...

Comment: @OhadSchneider nope. There's still an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1028) to get the new Roslyn based FxCop rules up and running on .NET Core projects. According to the latest comments we'll have to wait for .NET Core 1.1, which will lead to the death of .xproj anyway. :poop:

Comment: @OhadSchneider please see my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a workaround, which should do it until they'll (hopefully) fix it with the next release of .NET Core and Visual Studio. The trick is to execute the "good old" *FxCop* for the classic .NET Framework build, which is necessary to run an old fashioned code analysis.

The *project.json* for libraries should contain something like that:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "CODE_ANALYSIS" ]
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": "../../CodeAnalysis.cmd %compile:TargetFramework% %compile:Configuration% %compile:OutputFile% %compile:CompilerExitCode%"
  }
 }
```

The *project.json* for "apps" should include the actual runtime:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": "../../CodeAnalysis.cmd %compile:TargetFramework% %compile:Configuration% %compile:OutputFile% %compile:CompilerExitCode% %compile:RuntimeOutputDir%"
  }
 }
```

Thus, using the *postcompile* event makes it possible to run some kind of batch script to execute the classic *FxCop* (Visual Studio required!). I'm currently using a setup with three files:

- CodeAnalysis.cmd
- CodeAnalysis.ruleset
- CodeAnalysis.xml (dictionary)

The batch file "supports" the current .NET Framework 4.6 versions and looks like this:

```json
@echo off

if not [%4]==[0] (
  goto :eof
)

if not [%2]==[Release] (
  goto :eof
)

if [%1]==[net46] (
  set VERSION=v4.6
) else if [%1]==[net461] (
  set VERSION=v4.6.1
) else if [%1]==[net462] (
  set VERSION=v4.6.2
) else (
  goto :eof
)

if not [%5]==[] (
  set FILE=%5\%~nx3
) else (
  set FILE=%3
)

set PLATFORM=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\%VERSION%
set DIRECTORY=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\%VERSION%\Facades

set FXCOP=%VS140COMNTOOLS:Common7\Tools=Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop%FxCopCmd.exe
set RULES=%VS140COMNTOOLS:Common7\Tools=Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop%Rules

"%FXCOP%" /platform:"%PLATFORM%" /directory:"%DIRECTORY%" /rule:"-%RULES%" /ruleset:"=%~dp0CodeAnalysis.ruleset" /dictionary:"%~dp0CodeAnalysis.xml" /file:"%FILE%" /ignoregeneratedcode /console /culture:de-DE
```

It's not that handy like the ordinary built-in stuff, but the errors / warnings of *FxCop* appear within the *Error List* when using *Visual Studio* (sometimes a second build is necessary). They don't lead to a failed build though (maybe there's another trick...).

*CodeAnalysis.ruleset example:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="All Rules, except a few ones" ToolsVersion="14.0">
    <IncludeAll Action="Error" />
    <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
        <!-- CLS compliant -->
        <Rule Id="CA1014" Action="None" />
        <!-- COM visibility -->
        <Rule Id="CA1017" Action="None" />
    </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works indeed! One question though: in my case the compilation constants don't get evaluated for some reason e.g. when passing `%compile:TargetFramework%` from project.json the batch script receives the string `%compile:TargetFramework%` instead of the actual value. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, didn't had that issue. Are you using another event than "postcompile"?

Comment: Ah, you are right, I was using "postbuild". However, "postcompile" doesn't seem to be recognized as a valid event. Do you need `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"` for that?

Comment: That depends more likely on the tooling being used. I think the "older" dnu/dnx tooling had a postbuild script, while the "newer" dotnet tooling (Version 1.0.0-preview2-003131 on my machine) provides a postcompile event.

Comment: You're right, my version is 1.0.0-rc1, too old apparently. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey, can you show us an example of how a custom ruleset file should look like (CodeAnalysis.ruleset)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've been really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue for this on the ASP.NET Tooling GitHub site [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/255). It is currently unsupported but will hopefully get implemented soon. Code analysis will work again when the switch from xproj back to csproj is made.

## Update

[StyleCop.Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/DotNetCli.md) is now supported with xproj.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I only upvoted since it doesn't really resolve this.

Comment: .net core is at 1.0.1 now and still no sign of any Static Analysis tooling.

Comment: @WarrenP The `StyleCop.Analyzers` static analysis tool works using a workaround. Others will have to wait for the xproj to csproj move.

Comment: I was unable to get the workaround to work, either in the IDE or from a command line batch file.

Comment: @WarrenP I've been using it all week, it does 100% work.