# FxCop Analysis with .Netcore library failed in VS2015 update 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, fxcop, class-library

I was built my project(Class Library) in .Net core and trying to analyze my code using FxCop in VS2015.

But i am getting following error:
"could not identify platform for project"
[image]

Also i tried to set platform for my project. But i can't able to set it.
[image]

Any thing i missed here?

thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

By referring this link [Use code analysis with Visual Studio DNX project (.xproj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148225/use-code-analysis-with-visual-studio-dnx-project-xproj)
I have added following lines in project.Json file now its working.

```
"frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "CODE_ANALYSIS" ]
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

[image]

Note: After added the code in project.json file, close all visual studio application and start it. Then it will work.